# R script error in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, r

I've installed R on Ubuntu 19.10 and successfully installed the plugin 'Processing R Provider'.  However, when I try running a script (e.g. Scatterplot) I get an error (see the report at the end of the post).  I have queried this with the developers of the plugin, but it would appear to be a local issue.

I can launch R from a terminal as well.

Any suggestions?

```
2019-09-29T16:32:51     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/ProcessingToolbox.py", line 239, in executeAlgorithm
              ok, message = alg.canExecute()
              File "/home/neil/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/processing_r/processing/algorithm.py", line 279, in canExecute
              msg = RUtils.check_r_is_installed()
              File "/home/neil/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/processing_r/processing/utils.py", line 315, in check_r_is_installed
              universal_newlines=True) as proc:
              File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
              restore_signals, start_new_session)
              File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
              raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
             PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/R'

2019-09-29T16:38:57     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/ProcessingToolbox.py", line 239, in executeAlgorithm
              ok, message = alg.canExecute()
              File "/home/neil/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/processing_r/processing/algorithm.py", line 279, in canExecute
              msg = RUtils.check_r_is_installed()
              File "/home/neil/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/processing_r/processing/utils.py", line 315, in check_r_is_installed
              universal_newlines=True) as proc:
              File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
              restore_signals, start_new_session)
              File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
              raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
             PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/R'
```

Comment: Can you show the settings in the R section of Options.... Processing... Providers... R? I suspect your "R Folder" section might be wrong. It works fine if I leave that blank, QGIS finds my system R installation.

Comment: Thanks I wiped the R folder and it worked.

Comment: The sample R script Scatterplot now works, but I have installed Spatstat and the various categories do not appear.

Comment: That would be a different question - start a new question and describe the problem as fully as possible.